Is there automation tools or extension for Firefox to do some routine works?
Is there automation tools or extension for Firefox to do some routine works?
I need suggestions for Firefox extension.
The extension able to select Item from drop-down menu then click button then wait for output then print the output.

If this question is asking about browser automation in general, there are tools. Selenium is one such. If you're asking something else, please clarify.
